# imageView return getWidth zero

Tags: android, imageview

My imageView in xml:

```
<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ivManagePhoto"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

My code:

```
    ImageView ivManagePhoto;
    ivManagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivManagePhoto);
   double ivw = ivManagePhoto.getWidth();
```

When i try to get ivManagePhoto.getWidth(); that return 0, but i need to get mathparent size.

Comment: You want screen width size?

Comment: @Manishika, screen width size = 480, width imageView = ~400. I need to get this 400

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.getWidth();
            }
        });
```

or, try this:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
  viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      viewWidth = view.getWidth();
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this code will help you.

Comment: Does not work and to much code to get simple width :/

Comment: Size of imageView != screen size.

Comment: ok.. try to look on answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0

Answer (score 0):

You can wait to onwindowfocuschanged event. At this time UI items are already loaded

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        //get sizes you want
        Point screen_size=new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screen_size);
        int width = screen_size.x;
        int height = screen_size.y;
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```